# How non-executable are implemented?

Tags: attack-prevention, buffer-overflow

In the "[Hacking the art of Exploitation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271441)" its said that the basic idea of  [stack overflows attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow) is that the operating system can't differentiate instructions from data inside the stack ,and the solution to this problem was to implement a "non executable stack".

My question is how is this implemented ??

Comment: Well ,looks like it is , i haven't noticed because i didn't know what are (ASLR) and (DEP). 
What should i do know ? delete the question ?

Comment: dont worry, the question will be closed automatically soon. You don't need to do anything :) What you are talking about is called 'DEP'. 'ASLR' is a different thing, but similar in that it is memory-corruption-protection related.

Comment: @HSN do not worry that you didn't know - that's not the point of closing a question. The point of closing a question is to get you to the answer you needed in the first place. It is possible that you might not get such high quality answers again, so where a really high quality question exists that explains the topic well, we try to direct you to that so you get the best answer possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could compile with the stack protection flag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629685/when-and-how-to-use-gccs-stack-protection-feature is a similar question that asks how to enable stack protection for executables compiled with GCC.